Kubeadm showing errors about reading configuration from the cluster and missing etcd certificates
I have 3 master-worker nodes in the cluster. on one of them kubeadm is showing errors when checking for expired certificates:
# kubeadm certs check-expiration
[check-expiration] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[check-expiration] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
[check-expiration] Error reading configuration from the Cluster. Falling back to default configuration

CERTIFICATE                         EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
admin.conf                          Jul 31, 2025 11:44 UTC   343d            ca                      no      
apiserver                           Jul 31, 2025 11:44 UTC   343d            ca                      no      
!MISSING! apiserver-etcd-client                                                                      
apiserver-kubelet-client            Jul 31, 2025 11:44 UTC   343d            ca                      no      
controller-manager.conf             Jul 31, 2025 11:44 UTC   343d            ca                      no      
!MISSING! etcd-healthcheck-client                                                                    
!MISSING! etcd-peer                                                                                  
!MISSING! etcd-server                                                                                
front-proxy-client                  Jul 31, 2025 11:44 UTC   343d            front-proxy-ca          no      
scheduler.conf                      Jul 31, 2025 11:44 UTC   343d            ca                      no      

CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
ca                      May 27, 2032 16:30 UTC   7y              no      
!MISSING! etcd-ca                                                
front-proxy-ca          May 27, 2032 16:30 UTC   7y              no   

on other nodes the output is different:
# kubeadm certs check-expiration
[check-expiration] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[check-expiration] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
W0822 13:04:00.381912 2829476 utils.go:69] The recommended value for "clusterDNS" in "KubeletConfiguration" is: [A.B.C.D]; the provided value is: [E.F.G.H]

CERTIFICATE                EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
admin.conf                 Jul 31, 2025 11:43 UTC   343d            ca                      no      
apiserver                  Jul 31, 2025 11:43 UTC   343d            ca                      no      
apiserver-kubelet-client   Jul 31, 2025 11:43 UTC   343d            ca                      no      
controller-manager.conf    Jul 31, 2025 11:43 UTC   343d            ca                      no      
front-proxy-client         Jul 31, 2025 11:43 UTC   343d            front-proxy-ca          no      
scheduler.conf             Jul 31, 2025 11:43 UTC   343d            ca                      no      

CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
ca                      May 27, 2032 16:30 UTC   7y              no      
front-proxy-ca          May 27, 2032 16:30 UTC   7y              no      


I've checked /etc/etcd.env, all the certs are in place, the contents of the /etc/ssl/etcd/ssl/ is identical to that of other nodes
kubectl works* no problems with pod creation/deletion and other activities on that node (I even managed to renew the cluster certificates), but I'm still afraid it's gonna bite me in the REDACTED, if I, say, decide to upgrade the cluster normally on the sus node

what can I do to debug this issue?

@ Wasil W. Siargiejczyk Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

sorry for the delay. all the other certificates are in order, recently I have renewed them all. all the API pods work and accessible. strangely enough, etcdctl member list fails, but that's probably due to etcdctl not configured properly.

@ Wasil W. Siargiejczyk If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

The issue you are facing is kubeadm reports missing etcd certificates on one node could be the several potential reasons.
The Error reading configuration from the Cluster. Falling back to default configuration indicates that  kubeadm certs check - expiration.
As per this blog by Rob sewell:

certificate embedded in the kubeconfig file for the admin to use and
for kubeadm itself renewed certificate for serving the Kubernetes API
renewed certificate the apiserver uses to access etcd renewed
certificate for the API server to connect to kubelet renewed
certificate embedded in the kubeconfig file for the controller manager
to use renewed certificate for liveness probes to healthcheck etcd
renewed certificate for etcd nodes to communicate with each other
renewed certificate for serving etcd renewed certificate for the front
proxy client renewed certificate embedded in the kubeconfig file for
the scheduler manager to use renewed.
After renewing certificates. You must restart the kube-apiserver,
kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler and etcd, so that they can use
the new certificates.

If the issue is still not resolved try to run kubectl get pods  -n kube-system to check the status of the API server pod. If the API server is not running or if there any errors  try to  restart it using kubectl delete pod < api-server-pod-name> - n kube-system
Run etcdctl members list to verify the status of etcd members in the cluster and also check the etcd logs for any errors messages related to communication or authentication.
Refer to Sid’s Bytestream blog and  raynix  blog for more information.
